# Storage limitations on laptops

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, storage, hp-pavilion

I have an HP pavilion 14 model:bf103ne. I have a 1TB HDD in it and am looking to add an ssd. According to the product manual, there is only support for 256GB of SSD storage along with 1TB of HDD. (Product Manual: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05527168) Could someone please share why that is and what would happen if I added a 512GB SSD?
Thanks!

Comment: These are usually "supply" specs, not actual hardware limitations. You could very likely put two 4TB SSDs in there, or an SSD & HDD of pretty much any size with zero issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your manual, it can take a 512GB SSD drive.  The dual configuration is a bit confusing.  You might try two 512 GB SSD drives. OR, get a 2 TB HDDD 7200-rpm and stick with the existing SSD and/or try the 512GB SSD.

Supports 6.35 cm (2.5 in) SATA hard drives in 9.5 mm (.37-in) and 7.0 mm/7.2 mm (.28-in) thicknesses

Support for SSD + HDD

Support for M.2 SATA SSD

Accelerometer/hard drive protection support

Single hard drive configurations:

2-TB, 5400 rpm, 7.0/7.2 mm

1-TB, 5400 rpm, 7.0/7.2 mm

500-GB, 5400 rpm, 7.0/7.2 mm

M.2 SATA-3 configurations (TLC):

512 GB

256 GB

128 GB

Comment: I think that was supposed to be a table? It is completely unreadable.

Comment: I spread out the sentences (SU edit limitation) but it is entirely readable here. I will check again.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to "Dual storage configurations" in page 2, these are only the factory options avalable when buying.
I see no problems adding a 512GB SSD.